# How to use Facebook in Codename one to display user posts in list view using graph query

Tags: java, json, facebook, codenameone

I am trying to fetch users posts from Facebook in Codename one, but I am unable to fetch it, can anyone help me out from this issue.
Is there any another method to retrieve posts from facebook and display it in list, I am already tried out FacebookAccess but it won't work fine so I will just try to use graph query to deal with it.

```
    @Override
            public void fetchData(String token, Runnable callback) {
                ConnectionRequest req = new ConnectionRequest() {
                    @Override
                    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 Map<String, Object> parsed = parser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));                        
                       email = (String) parsed.get("email");
                        name = (String) parsed.get("name");
                        first_name = (String) parsed.get("first_name");
                        last_name = (String) parsed.get("last_name");
                         gender = (String) parsed.get("gender");
                        image = (String) ((Map) ((Map) parsed.get("picture")).get("data")).get("url").toString();
                        posts = (String) ((Map)  parsed.get("posts")).get("data").toString();

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parsed);
                            JSONObject posts_obj = obj.getJSONObject("posts");
                            JSONArray  data_arr=posts_obj.getJSONArray("data");
                            for(int i=0;i<data_arr.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject data_obj=data_arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String story = data_obj.getString("story");
                    String created_time = data_obj.getString("created_time");
                    String id = data_obj.getString("id");

                    Log.p(story + created_time + id);

                    if(data_obj.has("message")) {
                        String message = data_obj.getString("message");
                        Log.p(message);
                    }
                }
                        } catch (JSONException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void postResponse() {
                        callback.run();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
                        //access token not valid anymore
                        if (code >= 400 && code <= 410) {
                            doLogin(FacebookConnect.getInstance(), FacebookData.this, true);
                            return;
                        }
                        super.handleErrorResponseCode(code, message);
                    }
                };
                req.setPost(false);
                req.setUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me");
                req.addArgumentNoEncoding("access_token", token); //this statement is used to patch access token with url
                req.addArgumentNoEncoding("fields", "email,name,first_name,last_name,gender,picture.width(512).height(512),posts.limit(10)");
                //above statement is used to provide permission through url so server send data with respect ot permissions.
                NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(req);
            }
```

**It will throw following error:**

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,5 - login event triggered
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
[EDT] 0:0:30,141 - First NAme : Gaurav
[EDT] 0:0:30,158 - Last Name : Takte
[EDT] 0:0:30,158 - Email : gauravtakte@gmail.com
[EDT] 0:0:30,158 - Full Name : Gaurav Takte
[EDT] 0:0:30,158 - Gender : male
[EDT] 0:0:30,158 - Pcture : https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-1/c120.0.720.720/p720x720/14711282_1180682575359906_4087581028110405984_o.jpg?oh=79ddd802cba25d9ecc89d07322c06190&oe=59615E62
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:413)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:180)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:420)
    at com.facebook.connect.Connect$FacebookData$1.readResponse(Connect.java:263)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:733)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: So according to the error message, what you try to parse as JSON is not actually JSON. So your debugging obviously starts with checking what it actually is.

Comment: I will check and when I print it in the log it successfully print posts data, But the error remains same

Answer (score 0):

You are using the builtin Codename One `JSONParser` [documented here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html). Then passing parsed map object into a completely separate parser for some reason.

You read the first few values correctly so you understand how to use the `JSONParser` just continue extracting the data from the `Map` hierarchy. Notice you can place a breakpoint in the debugger and inspect the elements to understand what's going on.